# unable to update interface props using useEffect in function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

1. I'm trying to update `channelInfo` which is coming as props. Below is the interface in which it is coming from.

   ```
   export interface GridChannelCellProps extends FocusViewInjectedProps {
     channel?: channelTile;
     channelInfo: GridGuideV5Channel | undefined; 
     listItemIndex?: number;
     testID?: string;
     backgroundColor?: string;
     fastScroll?: boolean
   ```
2. I saved channelInfo in a new constant.

   ```
     const [channelDetails, setChannelDetails] = useState(channelInfo);
   ```
3. Now I'm passing `channelInfo` to `useEffect` as a second parameter to update it.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     setShowAltText(!channel?.image?.url);
     setChannelDetails(channelInfo => channelInfo);
   }, [channel, channelInfo]);
   ```

I'm not able to see any update in the UI, as I'm rendering A LIKE BUTTON component based on values in `channelInfo` .

4. Meanwhile this is working on page reload, but I need to update the button without a reload.

Comment: Missing a reproducible example, preferable in a sandbox, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `channelInfo` isn't referenced in the `useEffect` callback, so it's not a dependency, currently. Also, `setChannelDetails(channelInfo => channelInfo);` simply enqueues a state update with the previous state value, which won't trigger a rerender. It's rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Please provide a more complete and comprehensive code example.

Answer (score 1):

In the following statement:

```
setChannelDetails(channelInfo => channelInfo);
```

You are setting the current state value of `channelDetails` to its previous value. Thus, keeping the same value and not making any update.

This is explained in the ["Functional updates"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) section of the `useState` hook documentation:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

You should rather do the following, which would set the state value of `channelDetails` to the value of `channelInfo` that is received as a prop:

```
setChannelDetails(channelInfo);
```